# javascript show cursor after foucs()

Tags: javascript

When I double click the text, the text box shows. And, I want to show the cursor at the end of text box. The problem is the cursor does not show but when I press a key the character is typed at the end of text box.

HTML:

```
<div ondblclick="change_to_textbox()" id="A">the original text</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function change_to_textbox(){
  var newtext = document.getElementById("A").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("A").innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='B'>";
  document.getElementById("B").value = newtext;
  document.getElementById("B").focus();
}
```

How to show the cursor at the end of text box?

Comment: what do you mean by end of text box?

Comment: `document.getElementById("B").focus();`.. https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/xyoL0n77/

Comment: change focus to focus()

Comment: It is typo. The actual code is focus() but I still can't show cursor.

Comment: I know the problem. As I hash the page, so the cursor does not show.

Answer (score 1):

You should change **focus** to **focus()**

```
 document.getElementById("B").focus;
```

to

```
  document.getElementById("B").focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function change_to_textbox(){
  var newtext = document.getElementById("A").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("A").innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='B'>";
  document.getElementById("B").value = newtext;
  document.getElementById("A").focus();
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Yes you missed `focus()`

```js
function change_to_textbox(){
  var newtext = document.getElementById("A").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("A").innerHTML = "<input type='text' id='B'>";
  document.getElementById("B").value = newtext;
  document.getElementById("B").focus();
}
```

```html
<div ondblclick="change_to_textbox()" id="A">the original text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot that focus is a function.

Try:

```
document.getElementById("B").focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

instead 
document.getElementById("B").focus;

write
document.getElementById("B").focus();

.focus is a method so use with parentheses.